# Не работает JMenu

Tags: java

Я решил создать JMenu. Я полазил в настройках, все сделал, но когда я нажимаю на меню оно не работает

```
JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("File");
    mnNewMenu.setBounds(0, 0, 91, 22);
    contentPane.add(mnNewMenu);

    JMenuItem mntmNewProject = new JMenuItem("New Project");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmNewProject);

    JMenuItem mntmGg = new JMenuItem("Open Project");
    mntmGg.setSelected(true);
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmGg);

    JMenuItem mntmStartPage = new JMenuItem("Start Page");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmStartPage);

    JMenuItem mntmRenameProject = new JMenuItem("Rename Project");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmRenameProject);

    JMenuItem mntmExport = new JMenuItem("Export");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmExport);
```

Answer (score 0):

JMenu надо добавлять на фрейм напрямую, а не в contentPane, так:
`frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar)`;